# How I get a Element from a XML File

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, nodes

I want to get a Element from a XML File. But I don't know how I get a Element from The XML.

My XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="resources">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <resources>
    <id>id_SearchUser</id>         <!--Label lblSearchUser-->
    <text>Benutzer</text>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <id>id_location</id>           <!--Label lblLocation-->
    <text>Werk</text>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <id>id_Search</id>             <!--Button Button2-->
    <text>Suchen</text>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <id>id_User</id>                <!--Label lblUser-->
    <text>Benutzer</text>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <id>id_eMail</id>               <!-- Label lblEmail-->
    <text>eMail</text>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <id>id_Firstname</id>           <!--LinkLabel lnkFirstname-->
    <text>Vorname</text>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <id>id_Lastname</id>           <!--LinkLabel lnkLastname-->
    <text>Nachname</text>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <id>id_Telephonnumber</id>     <!--Label lblTelephon-->
    <text>Telefon</text>
  </resources>
</NewDataSet>
```

My Idea:

I get the location of a User. For Example "de" and than I want to call the GetXMLElement Method that give me the Content of a Element.

For Example:

I have a Label in my Application "id_SearchUser" and I want that this text property change to the Content of the  ...

...

```
<resources>
    <id>id_SearchUser</id>        
    <text>Benutzer</text>
</resources>
```

....

and the Text is than Benutzer.

My Method:

```
public string GetXMLElement()
{
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/de_language.xml"));
    XmlNode node = // ??
    return // node as string
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this?

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/de_language.xml"));
XElement element = document.Root.Elements("resources").FirstOrDefault(e => e.Element("id").Value == "id_SearchUser");
string text;
if (element != null)
  text = element.Element("text").Value;
```

Notice that I used `XDocument` instead of your `XmlDocument`, XDocument uses LINQ whereas XmlDocument uses XPATH to get nodes. It's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XQuery to get the element you want:

Here is a quick example:

```
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/de_language.xml"));
var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
var nodes = nav.select("/xpath/to/the/node/you/want/to/select"); // for example /resources/id/text
nodes.First();
// now nodes.Current.Value is the value of the node you've just selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access nodes by xpath

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use xpath to select the nodes you need. The [xpath reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115.aspx) is an excellent resource for this.

You then need to use the [SelectSingleNode method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw.aspx) to find that node.

Comment: I wouldn't want to use XPath for this. I'd use LINQ to XML, which is *really* simple, and doesn't require embedding one language within another.